# MapBox User Location Icon (Android)

Tags: android, api, geolocation, mapbox

I use MapBox for my Android App, and I need to modify the standard blue "dot" that is used to indicate the current user location and orientation.

I found this thread indicating that past MapBox Android APIs offered methods to modify the User Location Icon:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk-legacy/issues/717

The thread mentions these methods:

```
mapView.getUserLocationOverlay().setDirectionArrowBitmap();
mapView.getUserLocationOverlay().setPersonBitmap();
```

The newest MapBox Android SDK does not show these methods.  Does anyone know replacements for these methods or alternatives to modifying the User Location Icon?

The maven archive is here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/0.7.4/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/overlay/UserLocationOverlay.java#UserLocationOverlay.setDirectionArrowBitmap%28com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.overlay.Bitmap%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MapBox responded to a request to clarify replacements for these methods, saying:

> As for changing location of a custom Marker to show movement, the best bet is to add and remove Markers when you need to show progress. Depending on how quickly you need to refresh the location, this approach might look a bit choppy, but it is the best workaround at this point. This would be done via

```
MapView.addMarker()
```

and

```
MapView.removeAnnotation()
```

That is not an ideal solution, but it should get the job done for now.

Answer (score 1):

I have Added a bus icon and you can change it as You Want.

```
    @SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})
private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
    // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
    if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(mainActivity)) {
        // Activate the MapboxMap LocationComponent to show user location
        // Adding in LocationComponentOptions is also an optional parameter
        locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
        locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(mainActivity, loadedMapStyle);
        locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

        // Create and customize the LocationComponent's options
        LocationComponentOptions customLocationComponentOptions = LocationComponentOptions.builder(getActivity())
                .foregroundDrawable(R.drawable.bus)
                .build();


        // Get an instance of the component
        locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();

        LocationComponentActivationOptions locationComponentActivationOptions =
                LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(getActivity(), loadedMapStyle)
                        .locationComponentOptions(customLocationComponentOptions)
                        .build();

        // Activate with options
        locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(locationComponentActivationOptions);

        // Set the component's camera mode
        locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);

        //  IconFactory iconFactory = IconFactory.getInstance(getActivity());
        //  mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(iconFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus)));

    } else {
        permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
        permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(mainActivity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Markers indicate single locations on the map. You can customize your markers by changing the default color, or replacing the marker icon with a custom image. Info windows can provide additional context to a marker.

```
MarkerView markerView = new MarkerView(new LatLng(LAT,LONG), customView);
                                             
markerViewManager.addMarker(markerView);
                                            
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {                                 
        MarkerViewManager markerViewManager = new MarkerViewManager(mapView, mapboxMap);
                                             
    }
});
```

markerViewManager.removeMarker(markerView);

Enough talk, let us see some
ok we'll check it
There's nothing here, yet.
If you see
you'll need
I'll check and reply
Now you can
don't worry

```
@Volatile
synchronized intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

// for Log 
public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getSimpleName();
```