# Mapbox: change drawable of my location

Tags: android, mapbox

I would like to change my location indicator from blue circle to custom drawable:
[image]

AFAIK, The only one way how I can change this blue circle to custom drawable is using `styles.xml` and I can't change style programmatically:

```
     <style name="CustomLocationLayer" parent="LocationLayer">
        <item name="backgroundDrawable">@drawable/CUSTOM_DRAWABLE</item>
        <item name="foregroundDrawable">@drawable/CUSTOM_DRAWABLE</item>
    </style>

locationPlugin.applyStyle(R.style.CustomLocationLayer)
```

But I need to generate this `CUSTOM_DRAWABLE` in runtime and I can't find any method/setter to use for change it in runtime. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Check out this Url [Change Current User Icon in Mapbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56291609/4445489)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found ? We can't do that without workaround.

The only one way is to hide this blue indicator using `styles.xml`

```
<style name="EmptyLocationLayer" parent="LocationLayer">
        <item name="foregroundDrawable">@drawable/ic_location_indicator_workaround</item>
        <item name="backgroundDrawable">@drawable/ic_location_indicator_workaround</item>
        <item name="accuracyColor">#00000000</item>
</style>

<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="14dp"
    android:height="14dp"
    android:viewportHeight="14.0"
    android:viewportWidth="14.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M7,7m-7,0a7,7 0,1 1,14 0a7,7 0,1 1,-14 0"/>
</vector>
```

After initialising `LocationPlugin` we need to apply this style:

```
locationPlugin?.applyStyle(R.style.EmptyLocationLayer)
```

And before calling

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude), DEFAULT_ZOOM))
```

I'm adding custom marker into map `map.addMarker(customMarker)`